# free(): double free detected in tcache 2 when deleting a list

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Stanza
{
    struct Stanza *avanti, *sinistra, *destra;
};
static struct Stanza *Stanza = NULL;
static struct Stanza *stanza_inizio = NULL;
static struct Stanza *lista_stanze = (struct Stanza *)&stanza_inizio;

void insertinlist(struct Stanza *Stanza)
{
    lista_stanze = Stanza;
    if (stanza_inizio == NULL)
        stanza_inizio = lista_stanze;
    else
    {
        lista_stanze->avanti = stanza_inizio;
        stanza_inizio = Stanza;
    }
}
void createElement(void)
{
    Stanza = (struct Stanza *)malloc(sizeof(struct Stanza));
    if (Stanza == NULL)
    {
        exit(2);
    }
    Stanza->avanti = Stanza->sinistra = Stanza->destra = NULL;
    stanza_inizio = Stanza;
    insertinlist(Stanza);
}
void delete (void)
{
    struct Stanza *scorritore = stanza_inizio;
    struct Stanza *successivo;
    if (scorritore == NULL)
    {
        // nothing
    }
    else
    {
        while (scorritore != NULL)
        {
            successivo = scorritore->avanti;
            free(scorritore); // error: double free detected in tcache
            scorritore = successivo;
        }
        stanza_inizio = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    createElement();
    delete ();
}
```

I'm getting the error "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" caused by delete() function, when calling free, but can't understand why.
I tried to use this code in a new blank file with a different list and it works perfectly fine, but with thislist something unknown to me is wrong

What's wrong here?

Comment: If possible, please provide a [mre]. This will make it easier for other people to help you.

Comment: ok I'm gonna edit right now

Comment: @WhozCraig is better now? I cannot give a precise number of items in the list as it varies every time

Comment: @WhozCraig now it compiles, btw what are the global variables that I can put local?

Comment: @WhozCraig : The reformatting you applied is certainly more readable but you changed <stdlib.h> to <stdio.h> preventing it from compiling (implicit `malloc()`)- take care not to change the code when making whitespace changes.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this line in `delete()`:

```
successivo = scorritore -> avanti;
```

`successivo` and `scorritore->avanti` have the same value in the first iteration of teh whole =-loop, so on the second iteration, there is an attempt to delete an already free'd block:
[image]

So the problem is in the construction of the list rather then the `delete()` function.  The line:

```
stanza_inizio = Stanza;
```

in `createElement()` seems unlikely to be intended.  It prevents the first-time initialisation block in `insertinlist()`:

```
if (stanza_inizio == NULL)
    stanza_inizio = lista_stanze;
else{
```

from running.

Deleting:

```
stanza_inizio = Stanza;
```

from `createElement()` at least allows the code to run to completion.  I would not care to say whether the code is actually semantically correct beyond that correction (but I kind of doubt it).

However this initialisation at least is suspect:

```
static struct Stanza *lista_stanze = (struct Stanza *) &stanza_inizio;
```

`&stanza_inizio` has type `struct Stanza**` but you assign it to a `struct Stanza*`.  It is unconditionally assigned in `insertinList()` in any event so it really serves no purpose.

Comment: @LorisSimonetti The take-home here perhaps is to use a debugger (as I did for the screenshot above - albeit the somewhat rudimentary gdbonline) - debugging by posting questions of SO will be painfully slow.

Comment: I tried to remove if (stanza_inizio == NULL) this condition and the code continues to work as it should, but I can't get rid of this double free error.

Comment: I even tried to add "scorritore = scorritore -> avanti;" before the while in delete, there is no way.

Comment: if I change &stanza_inizio to stanza_inizio I get: "error: initializer element is not constant"

Comment: I know, but my changes are kinda related to your question. as you said "stanza_inizio = Stanza; prevents the first-time initialisation block in insertinlist():
if (stanza_inizio == NULL)
    stanza_inizio = lista_stanze;
else{
" so I tried both remove stanza_inizio = Stanza and even remove the condition

Comment: do you mean stanza_inizio = Stanza?

Comment: oh ok sorry then!

Comment: by the way, I removed `stanza_inizio = Stanza;` but as you supposed, that's not the right way, I get a segmentation fault in another part of the program

Comment: I put the check on your answer, because you are right! but anyway about cargo-cult coding ... it is a code of about 1500/1600 lines, it is obvious that I do not post it all, and obviously no that I did not understand what I posted (otherwise I would not have asked)

Comment: @LorisSimonetti  Correction delete: the line from `createElement()` (answer edited).  It runs then at https://onlinegdb.com/SAeX6JaHd.  If you are getting a seg-fault that is likely a different error, and possibly not the same code as in your original question (since you said you have not posted it all - clearly the fragment you posted was suspect in other ways 1600 lines will have other bugs).

Comment: Just solved by adding a counter in of elements in the list in the while loop, decrementing it every time since the condition turn to be false. like `while (scorritore != NULL && nStanze)` thanks for your help!